# Hosting wordpress on Amazon

Tags: hosting, amazon

I have a client who has their site hosted somewhere where they are maxing out (it's a huge site). They're looking to continue hosting their future content elsewhere and I thought of Amazon- is this possible and how would this be done?

Comment: Hosting recommendations are off topic now, Old questions and answers : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting-recommendation?sort=votes&pageSize=15

Answer (score 1):

Read up on using [WordPress on an EC2 in AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html). You'll first need to create a [LAMP stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html). Chances are, if you couldn't google that far, you'll need to find someone to do it for you.